# Why there is a python version besides the package version?

Tags: python, pycharm, versioning

When I check the version of a package, I get a python version in parentheses. What does it mean?
[image: eb package version and Python in parenthesis]

This python 3.7.3 does not match with the PyCharm interpreter I am using (python 3.8). Is that the reason? Should I worry the version between parentheses is not the same as my python project interpreter?

Comment: There is a program "eb" which has a version (of eb), and such program use Python (which has a version, which it is independent of eb). It seems that same program eb can run on different python version. So are you saying that the env "GreatKart" is not using Python3.7? So maybe the application was frozen. Just check eb: it is a binary or a python file?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you have many python versions installed on your computer.
You probably need to pip install again the same package for the python version you are using with your Pycharm if you want them to work correctly.

if you are not sure how to do that with CMD commands,
you can access your Pycharm, look for "Python packages" at the bottom, and then search for your package.
You can see there is this package is installed already or not.
and if not - just hit the 'install' button.
after that, you are ready to go.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).